# Main function returns wrong value in C

Tags: c, function, perl, return, return-value

I have program in C where I compute something and result of that (integer) I need to return back to parent process, but it returns wrong values.

For example `app.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio>

int main()
{
    int i = 53400;

    return i;
}
```

Parent process (in Perl language):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $res = system("./app");
print $res."\n";
```

If I return `0` in C, I get in parent process value of `0`.
If I return `1` in C, I get in parent process value of `256`.
If I return `2` in C, I get in parent process value of `512`.

So I thought that it is just multiples by 256, but I was wrong because if I return `53400` in C, I get in parent process value of `38912` which is not multiple of 256.

So how can I get correct value from child process in parent?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what is solution? Because I need to return value back to parent process.

Comment: `main()` return value won't be received by the parent process. You'd need to use some other mechanism to pass it, like IPC, files, shared memory, etc

Comment: According to [perldoc system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) : *"The return value is the exit status of the program as returned by the wait call. To get the actual exit value, shift right by eight."*

Comment: @HåkonHægland if I shifted right by eight value `53400` in C, I got value `152` in Perl.

Comment: @tomsk I think only return values between 0 and 255 are valid. It seems like the return value from the C program is logical `AND`ed with `0xff`

Comment: @tomsk See also [What is the min and max values of exit codes in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418784/45537)

Comment: Im thinking what is easiest solution to return that value from child process back to parent, because I need it.

Comment: @tomsk Maybe just push it to STDOUT: `std::cout << i;` from C++ and then use backticks in Perl: ```my $out = `./app` ``` to retrieve the output from the command

Comment: (`printf("%d", i)` in C)